# A simple plot for many curves with different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following data frame which contains 4 columns of data in addition to the vector of labels c.

```
Time <-c(1:4)

d<-data.frame(Time,
x1= rpois(n = 4, lambda = 10),
x2= runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 10),
x3= rpois(n = 4, lambda = 5),
x4= runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 5),
c=c(1,1,2,3))
```

I would like to use `ggpolt` to plot 4 curves`"x1,..,x4"` above each others where each curve is colored according to the label. So curves `x1` and `x2` are colored by the same color since they have the same label where as curves `x3` and `x4` in different colors.

I did the following

```
d %>% pivot_longer(-c(Time,x1,x2,x3,x4))%>%
   rename(class=value) %>% select(-name) %>%
   pivot_longer(-c(Time,class)) %>%
   mutate(Label=ifelse(Time==max(Time,na.rm = T),name,NA),
          Label=ifelse(duplicated(Label),NA,Label)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x=Time,y=value,color=factor(class),group=name))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(color='class')+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue','green'))+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = Label),
                   nudge_x = 1.5,
                   na.rm = TRUE,show.legend = F,color='black')
```

but I don't get the needed plot, the resulted curves are not colored according to the label. I want `x1` and `x2` in red, `x3` in blue and `x4` in green.

---

**To add:** I would like to obtain the same plot above in the following general case, where I can't add the vector `c` to the data frame as `length(c)` is not equal to `length(x1)=...=length(x4)`

```
Time <-c(1:5)
d<-data.frame(Time,
x1= rpois(n = 5, lambda = 10),
x2= runif(n = 5, min = 1, max = 10),
x3= rpois(n = 5, lambda = 5),
x4= runif(n = 5, min = 1, max = 5))
```

and `c=c(1,1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out in your comments, it is only possible to put the vector of colors as a column in the original `data.frame` because it happens to be square, but this is a dangerous way to store the information because the colors really belong to the columns rather than the rows. It's better to assign the colors separately and then `join` into the long format data by variable name prior to plotting.

Below is an example of how I'd do this with your data.

First, prepare the data without the color mapping for each variable, we'll do that next:

```
# load necessary packages
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

# set seed to make simulated data reproducible
set.seed(1)

# simulate data
Time <-c(1:4)

d <- data.frame(Time,
              x1 = rpois(n = 4, lambda = 10),
              x2 = runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 10),
              x3 = rpois(n = 4, lambda = 5),
              x4 = runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 5))
```

Next, make a separate `data.frame` that maps the color grouping to the variable names. At some point you'll want to make this a `factor` (i.e. discrete rather than continuous) to map it to color so I just do it here but it can be done later in the `ggplot` call if you prefer. Per your request, this solution easily scales with your dataset without needing to manually set each level, but **it requires that your vector of color mappings is in the same order and the same length as the variable names in `d` unless you have some other way to establish that relationship.**

```
# create separate df with color groupings for variable in d
color_grouping <- data.frame(var = names(d)[-1],
                             color_group = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 3)))
```

Then you `pivot_longer` and do a `join` to merge the color mapping with the data for plotting.

```
# pivot d to long and merge in color codes
d_long <- d %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Time, names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>%
  left_join(., color_grouping)

# inspect final table prior to plotting to confirm color mappings
head(d_long, 4)

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Time var   value color_group
#   <int> <chr> <dbl> <fct>
# 1     1 x1     8    1
# 2     1 x2     1.56 1
# 3     1 x3     4    2
# 4     1 x4     4.97 3
```

Finally, generate line plot where `color` is mapped to the `color_group` variable. To ensure you get one line per original variable you also need to set `group = var`. For more info on this check the documentation on [grouping](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html).

```
# plot data adding labels for each line
p <- d_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = value, group = var, color = color_group)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(color='class') +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue','green')) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = var),
                   data = d_long %>% slice_max(order_by = Time, n = 1),
                   nudge_x = 1.5,
                   na.rm = TRUE,
                   show.legend = F,
                   color='black')

p
```

This produces the this plot:

[image: grouped line plot]

In your comment you suggested wanting to separate out and stacking the plots. I'm not sure I fully understood, but one way to accomplish this is with [faceting](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html).

For example if you wanted to facet out separate panels by `color_group`, you could add this line to the plot above:

```
p + facet_grid(rows = "color_group")
```

Which gives this plot:

[image: faceted plot]

Note that the faceting variable must be put in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path, but you need a little bit of a different structure to use `ggplot`:

```
# delete old color column
d$c <- NULL 

# reshape df
plot.d <- reshape2::melt(d, id.vars = c("Time"))

# create new, correct color column
plot.d$c <- NA
plot.d$c[plot.d$variable == "x1"] <- 1
plot.d$c[plot.d$variable == "x2"] <- 1
plot.d$c[plot.d$variable == "x3"] <- 2
plot.d$c[plot.d$variable == "x4"] <- 3

# plot
ggplot(plot.d, aes(x=Time, y=value, color=as.factor(c), group = variable))+
  geom_line() +
  labs(color='class')+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue','green'))
```

Note that I omitted the labels for brevity, but you can add them back in using the same logic. The code above gives the following result:

[image: ggplot2 result]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your solution, you insert color labels manually so if there are a lot  of column, say 100 then I need to do this manually! Is there a simpler way to do this? Additionally, how could I add the columns names to the curves in the plot?

Comment: See the answer of @MarBlo, it looks more complete than mine. Edit: Was just deleted, but maybe it will be re-added.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see it previously and now it is deleted

Comment: Is it possible to tell me how to plot separated curves in the same plot. I mean to plot the curves above each other in the same figure?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for how I understood your question.
The DF is brought in the long format, the variable `c` is replaced with `mutate / case_when` with the number code you have used.

I have set a seed for better reproducibility.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(1)
# YOUR DATA
Time <- c(1:4)
d <- data.frame(Time,
  x1 = rpois(n = 4, lambda = 10),
  x2 = runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 10),
  x3 = rpois(n = 4, lambda = 5),
  x4 = runif(n = 4, min = 1, max = 5),
  c = c(1, 1, 2, 3)
)


d %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = x1:x4) %>%     # make it long
  mutate(c = as.factor(case_when(    # replace consistently
    name == "x1" | name == "x2" ~ 1, # according to YOUR DATA
    name == "x3" ~ 2,
    name == "x4" ~ 3
  ))) %>%
  mutate(
    Label = ifelse(Time == max(Time, na.rm = T), name, NA),
    Label = ifelse(duplicated(Label), NA, Label)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = value, color = c, group = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(color = "class") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green")) + # YOUR CHOICE
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = Label),
    nudge_x = 1.5,
    na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = F, color = "black"
  )
```

[image]

**ADDED**

You could leave the `c` out and color according to name.
The color code was neccessary because you wanted 2 names with the same color. If that is not needed, the following code can do it.

```
d %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = x1:x4) %>%     # make it long
  mutate(
    Label = ifelse(Time == max(Time, na.rm = T), name, NA),
    Label = ifelse(duplicated(Label), NA, Label)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = value, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = Label),
    nudge_x = 1.5,
    na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = F, color = "black"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I look for but I still have a question as in the edit if you allow to me. Here, the length of c is equal to "the length of each variable" so I can add it to the data frame d. What if the number is different? I mean if length(x1=x2=x3=x4) = 5 but length(c)=4? I can't join c to the data frame so how can I do the same plot? Hope that I am clear.

Comment: You can control `c` within `mutate / case_when`. Even in your original DF - which I have used here - there are 4 names (x1,...,x4) and only 3 `c`'s. The colors in `scale_color_manual` are the ones you have chosen. You can leave this line out and ggplot will create as many colors as needed. I hope I have understood your question right.

Comment: thanks a lot. Is it possible to plot them above each other and not to be interacted?

 Last question I swear :), Is there an easier and simpler way  to specify the color of each column other than insert it manually as name == "x1" ~1...I mean it is ok for 4 columns but for a huge number of columns as 50 this would be a pain

Comment: As you point out, it is only possible to put the vector of colors as a column in the original `data.frame` because it happens to be square, but this is a dangerous way to store the information because the colors really belong to the columns rather than the rows. It's better to assign the colors as a separate `vector` and then `join` the color vector into the long format days by variable name prior to plotting. Hope that helps automate a general solution.

Comment: @DanAdams Couldyou please add a small code to do this because really I don't understand what do exactly "because of my bad level of programming :)"

Comment: Sure, I'm just on my phone, but I'll add an answer with full code when I'm at my computer later.